# Dynamic append of option into select is not working

Tags: jquery-ui

DDL is not refreshing with new set of options

$("#selectid").live('change', function () {
                if ($('option:selected', $(this)).text() == '--Next 50--') {

```
                var currentFifty = (parseInt($(this).val()) - 1);

                var upperFifty = parseInt(currentFifty + 50);

                var cOptions = '';

                for (var i = currentFifty; i < upperFifty; i++) {

                    if (collection[i].ID != null && collection[i].ID != "undefined") {
                        cOptions = cOptions + "<option value=" + collection[i].ID + ">" + collection[i].Text + "</option>";

                    }


                }

                alert($(this).html());

                $(this).append(cOptions);

                $(this).append($("<option></option>").val((upperFifty + 1)).html("--Next 50--"));

                var allhtml = ($(this).html());

                $(this).trigger('refresh');



            }
        });
```